# How to make a justified colored text panel with text continuing around it

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes, text

I am a beginner to LaTeX and am trying to make a right or left-justified colored panel with text in it, while text continues around it. I have tried with both a minipage and with defining a textbox using `tcolorbox`, but I'm not able to get the normal page text to continue around either.

Code sample:

```
% Placement
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

% Textboxes
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{textbox}[1][]{%
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  colback=PaleGoldenrod,
  height=10cm,
  attach title to upper,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
...

Lorem ipsum doler et cetera..

\hfill\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\begin{flushright}
  \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{PaleGoldenrod}{
    \parbox[t][5cm][c]{5.3cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} I would like there to be text to the left

   }%
  }%
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}


\begin{textbox}[width=7cm]
\begin{flushright}
I want there to be text to the right
\end{flushright}
\end{textbox}

Lorem ipsum doler et cetera..
```

[image: myproblem]

I'm sorry if this is a beginner question - I feel like this is a common request but I couldn't find an answer online.

Comment: You didn't attach the #1 to an option, so 'tcolorbox' doesn't know what to do with that. I am going to post an answer too, using the `textbox` environment you created.

Answer (score 1):

As promised another way to achieve what you wanted to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{lefttextbox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=LightGoldenrod1,    % PaleGoldenrod isn't defined in x11names
%   height=10cm,                % uncomment when needed
    width=7cm,
    attach title to upper,
    halign title=flush left,
    coltitle=DarkGoldenrod4,
    title=#1 --\space,
    halign=flush left,
    right=7.5mm                 % just to amplify the alignment
}

\newtcolorbox{righttextbox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=LightGoldenrod1, %
    %   height=10cm,
    width=7cm,
    attach title to upper,
    halign title=flush right,
    coltitle=DarkGoldenrod4,
    title=#1 --\space,
    halign=flush right,
    left=7.5mm
}

%===== Paracol settings ===== 
\usepackage{paracol}

\footnotelayout{m}
\globalcounter{table}
\globalcounter{figure}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

\columnratio{0.50,0.50}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[2]
\switchcolumn[1]
    \begin{lefttextbox}[Left aligned]
        \lipsum[1][1-2]
    \end{lefttextbox}
\switchcolumn[0]*                   % ensures correct alignment of column entries
    \begin{righttextbox}[Right aligned - ]
        \lipsum[1][3-4]
    \end{righttextbox}
\switchcolumn[1]
    \lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

    \lipsum[3]
    
\end{document}
```

You'll have to adjust certain options to fit your need. For example, the height and/or width of your boxes, the colour of the text and/or background, etc.

The MWE results in:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This a quick approach which you can experiment with

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
    ...
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{7cm}
        \begin{flushright}
            \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{
                \parbox[t][5cm][c]{5.3cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} I would like there to be text to the left
                }%
            }%
        \end{flushright}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    
    Lorem ipsum doler et cetera..
    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{7cm}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray}{
            \parbox[t][5cm][c]{5.3cm}{ \hspace*{0.25cm} I would like there to be text to the right
            }%
        }%
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{wrapfigure}

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.

This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel. This is some normal text that will continue around the colored panel.
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]